# Problem in exporting excel sheet using Office Interop

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, office-interop, excel-2013

I have a page that exports the data to an excel workbook in 3 different worksheets (ASP.net C#) with graphs. The page is working fine on my development machine but when I am running this page on server, it is giving me the following error:

**Unable to cast COM object of type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208D5-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).**

I tried almost everything I found on web to fix it but no luck.
I saw same problem on stackoverflow where someone suggested to delete a key from the registry editor:

> Start--> Run --> regedit -->
>   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT-->TypeLib-->{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
>   --> 1.8/1.7 (Delete this)

But in my case there is only 1 key "1.8" in the registry editor. There is no other key (as shown in the screenshot below)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcB2h.jpg)

I have tried the code with my local IIS and it's working fine.

MS Office 2013 is installed on server. Earlier it was MS Office 2010 installed, but I upgraded to 2013.

Please help.

Comment: Excel interop is not generally recommended for server-side execution.

Comment: Excel should *not* be used on the server. Imagine having 10 concurrent calls, each one starting a new Excel instance. Use a library like EPPlus to create real xlsx files. It can be as easy as writing `sheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(someList)`

Comment: BTW that error may just mean that Excel isn't installed on the server, or that the wrong version was found

Comment: Is MS office installed on the server? Lots of servers don't have it. And did you know that interop uses a full office instance running the in the background, including all the memory and cpu resources that implies? It's not usually a great choice for web apps you want to scale well.

Comment: BTW installing Excel on the server probably needs a license for every end user. It simply isn't used that way

Comment: MS office 2013 is installed on the server. Earlier it was 2010, it was upgraded to 2013

Comment: You shouldn't have upgraded - Office 2010 is still the most stable version... In any case, I concur with others' comments that Office interop should *not* be used server-side. There's a KB article to that effect. Instead, consider leveraging the Open XML file format using the Open XML SDK or a similar library.